# Does a theory $(\sim, =)$ admit quantifier elimination?

Tags: model-theory, quantifiers, quantifier-elimination

We have $\sim$ relation of equivalence and $=$. We also know that there are
infinite number of finite classes of equivalence. Does the theory with signature $(\sim, =)$ admits QE?

My answer is no, but I don't know how to prove it strong. We can make an infinite number of equivalence classes of size 1 and one class of size two.
Then predicate $P(x) = \exists z (x\sim z \land x\ne z)$. It's true for class of size two and false for others, but I don't know how to prove it correctly.

Comment: Exactly what theory are you asking about? The condition "there are infinitely many finite equivalence classes" is not first-order axiomatizable...

Comment: Do you mean to take a particular structure $(M,\sim)$ in which $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $M$ with infinitely many finite classes and then look at the complete theory $\text{Th}(M)$?